# Subfloor, underlayment and backer board

Tags: subfloor, ceramic-tile, underlayment, backer-board

So long story short… When starting a bathroom rehab I installed 23/32” OSB (exposure 1 panel) and I planned on using 1/4” Hardiebacker board for ceramic penny tile sheets. Finally getting to this point to apply I noticed with a proper level a dip in a high traffic section (little more than 1/4” over 4 ft area). I wanted to shim under the Hardie backer (~2ft x 2ft section) with a wood plywood or something suitable for thinset and the application. Is this okay and any suggestions? Other note, I have Schlulter Allset thinset mortar from the bath install and was going to use that between Hardie and OSB. If this sounds dumb, do I just add 1/2” plywood to OSB with shims to flatten and then do backer board?

Side questions. If I add plywood to OSB, is wonderboard or concrete board better to use than hardiebacker or fiber board for bathroom floor?

Anything else to note with penny tile applications and these backer boards?

Answer (score 1):

The Durock installation instructions explicitly allow OSB with a layer of thinset over the top. The TCNA Handbook has an OSB subfloor detail, but with plywood underlayment. ANSI A108 specifies plywood all over the place, but never OSB.

A 2ft x 2ft x 1/4in section is small enough to use a nice product like Henry 549.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like OSB, but it's there, so I would glue and screw the hardiebacker to the OSB. Then pour leveling compound over the entire floor. I don't like any moisture on OSB, because it doesn't like moisture. So no thin set.

(If the height of the floor is not an issue, it would be my preference to put down 1/2 inch Hardiebacker and leveling compound.)

I then have a smooth flat floor to apply the penny tile.